# Sum different row in column based on second column value

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have an Orders table (simplified)

```
OrderId,
SalesPersonId,
SaleAmount,
CurrencyId,
...
```

I am attempting to create a report on this table, I'm hoping for something like:

```
SalesPersonId   TotalCAD    TotalUSD
1               12,345.00   6,789.00
2               7,890.00    1,234.00
```

I'd prefer not to do a self join (perhaps I'm optimizing prematurely, but this seems inefficient) IE:

```
SELECT SalesPersonId, SUM(OrdersCAD.SaleAmount), SUM(OrderUSD.SaleAmount)
FROM Orders
    LEFT JOIN Orders AS OrdersCAD ON Orders.OrderID AND Orders.CurrencyID = 1
    LEFT JOIN Orders AS OrdersUSD ON Orders.OrderID AND Orders.CurrencyID = 2
```

But I cannot think of another way to do this, any ideas?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use a CASE block:

```
SELECT
  SalesPersonId,
  SUM(
    CASE CurrencyID
      WHEN 1 THEN SaleAmount
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS TotalCAD,
  SUM(
    CASE CurrencyID
      WHEN 2 THEN SaleAmount
      ELSE 0
    END
  ) AS TotalUSD
FROM Orders
GROUP BY SalesPersonId
```

Comment: Simply awesome. I have wanted to know how to do this for sometime. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Try This:

```
SELECT SalesPersonId, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyID = 1 THEN SaleAmount ELSE 0 END) as CAD, 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CurrencyID = 2 THEN SaleAmount ELSE 0 END) as USD
FROM ORDERS
```

Answer (score 0):

Consider trying out a scalar-valued function (SQL Server 2000 or later).

```
CREATE FUNCTION dbo.GetOrdersSumByCurrency
(   
    @SalesPersonID INT, @CurrencyID INT 
)
RETURNS DECIMAL(10, 2) 
AS
BEGIN
    DECLARE @Sum DECIMAL(10, 2) 

    SELECT @Sum = ISNULL(SUM(SalesAmount), 0) FROM dbo.Orders 
    WHERE SalespersonID=@SalesPersonID AND CurrencyID = @CurrencyID

    RETURN @Sum

END
```

Then execute SQL such as this to get the results (assumes you also have a separate salespersons table, or otherwise use instead SELECT DISTINCT SalesPersonId.... FROM Orders) :

```
    SELECT SalesPersonId, 
dbo.GetOrdersSumByCurrency(SalesPersonId, 1) AS SumUSD, dbo.GetOrdersSumByCurrency(SalesPersonId, 2) AS SumCAD 
    FROM SalesPersons
```

Be sure to run query plans to see if it performs as you need compared against the other possibilities suggested here, especially if you are processing a large quantity of data.